# node-gyp rebuild Fail on Mac OSX El Capitan

Tags: node.js, macos

I have a problem with `node-gyp rebuild`
Now I'm using xcode Version 7.2.1 (7C1002) and when I install the library like
`libxmljs@0.14.3` I have this error

```
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:110:17)
gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (child_process.js:1074:12)
gyp ERR! System Darwin 15.3.0
gyp ERR! command "node" "/Users/bob/.nvm/versions/node/v0.12.6/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js" "rebuild"
gyp ERR! cwd /Users/bob/Documents/Lavori/dg/workbook-app/node_modules/gulp-xml-editor/node_modules/libxmljs
gyp ERR! node -v v0.12.6
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v2.0.1
gyp ERR! not ok
npm ERR! Darwin 15.3.0
npm ERR! argv "/Users/bob/.nvm/versions/node/v0.12.6/bin/node" "/Users/bob/.nvm/versions/node/v0.12.6/bin/npm" "install"
npm ERR! node v0.12.6
npm ERR! npm  v2.11.2
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE

npm ERR! libxmljs@0.14.3 install: `node-gyp rebuild`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the libxmljs@0.14.3 install script 'node-gyp rebuild'.
npm ERR! This is most likely a problem with the libxmljs package,
npm ERR! not with npm itself.
npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
npm ERR!     node-gyp rebuild
npm ERR! You can get their info via:
npm ERR!     npm owner ls libxmljs
npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.
```

I tried with NVM with this node version

nvm 0.12.6 | nvm 0.12.7

But I have the same Problem

With command `node-gyp rebuild``

I have this output

```
gyp ERR! configure error
gyp ERR! stack Error: `gyp` failed with exit code: 1
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onCpExit (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/node-gyp/lib/configure.js:305:16)
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:110:17)
gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (child_process.js:1074:12)
gyp ERR! System Darwin 15.3.0
gyp ERR! command "node" "/usr/local/bin/node-gyp" "rebuild"
gyp ERR! cwd /my-path
gyp ERR! node -v v0.12.7
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.2.1
gyp ERR! not ok
```

Comment: Please add full logs starts from `npm install` till end.... current log doesn't say what is causing error

Comment: Check out https://github.com/nodejs/node-gyp/issues/489 for some solutions, but it might not be enough...

Comment: I know this is old, but I just ran into a similar looking problem and posted an answer on this question -  http://stackoverflow.com/a/38102743/765720.